# "All Questions Answers" hard to understand on new profile pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was looking at a profile that seems to have a new layout and was initially confused by the post listing:

[image: screenshot]

The "All Questions Answers" and "Votes Newest" text don't provide any indication as to which category and sort option is selected, and initially I didn't realize that they could be clicked at all.

Are the active ones supposed to be bolded or something?

(I'm using Chrome 48.0.2564.97 m on Windows 8.1, and see the same in IE 11 and FF 40.0.2.)

Comment: Place the cursor on an answer and it becomes underlined, doesn't that show it's a link? The tag in bold **Top Posts** show that you clicked on *Votes*. If you click on *Newest* the tag changes to **Newest Posts**

Comment: Although the functionality is present as @Mari-LouA points out, I think even simple separators can improve the presentation: "All | Questions | Answers || Votes | Newest".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not talking about the posts listed at all, if they were relevant they wouldn't be blacked out.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your condescension is fabulous, but I maintain that it's poor design as Lawrence and the votes seem to agree with.

Comment: It's not a bug, that's a fact. And you didn't answer my legitimate question. How long did it take for you to work it out? If it took more than ten minutes you might have a point.  Initially, I was more confused about your post than about the general layout, glad to see you've clarified your point. The layout feature I believe is common throughout StackExchange, so perhaps your observation would receive greater attention on meta Stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added margin between filters so it's easier to read/use. It will be live after our next production build.